# how to call a logout code after runs onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

have something like this in my main page:

```
<script language="javascript">


   window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
        var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
        if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
            evt = window.event;
        }       
        if (evt) {
            evt.returnValue = message;
        }
        return message;
    } 


</script>
```

What I want to do is call my logout piece of code in order to free all resources, but only if the user press leave page bottom, is that possible... know witch option did the user choice?

Thank you all, best regards

Comment: What exactly is the "logout pibuttonece of code" doing (how does it work) and what's wrong with the above code?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say "piece"... how ever the logout code it is a logout.action call in order to release all resources at the server, and I only want to call it if the user agree to leave the page

Answer (score 0):

use the `onunload` event:

```
window.onunload = function () {
    // your logout code
};
```

Comment: The problem with the onunload function it is the same... this event is triggered with the refresh, back or forward.

Is there a way that I can know where the event came from? I mean if the user press the refresh button or the close button?

Comment: other than interrogating the `event` object there is no way to tell what triggered the unload event.

Comment: see the documentation for the [event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event). for example, `event.target` will tell you the target of the event.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myclose = false;
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
     var messege = 'You have closed the browser. Do you want to logout from your application?';
    setTimeout('myclose=false',10);
    myclose=true;
    return myclose;
});
$(window).on('onunload', function(){
    if (myclose==true) 
    {
        //the url of your logout page which invalidate session on logout 
        alert('hello');
        location.replace('logout.php') ;
    }
});



    var myclose = false;
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
         var messege = 'You have closed the browser. Do you want to logout from your application?';
        setTimeout('myclose=false',10);
        myclose=true;
        return myclose;
    });
    $(window).on('onunload', function(){
        if (myclose==true) 
        {
            //the url of your logout page which invalidate session on logout 
            alert('hello');
            location.replace('logout.php') ;
        }
    });
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```